# camel mediate service via jms and rest

Tags: java, apache-camel

In my company we are starting to use web services. My plan is to provide access to services via 2 protocols, http and jms. Any external access (clients outside company network) to services will be typically via http and json through a restful URL, but internally if the service needs to invoke another service, it will do it via jms,  mainly to decouple the service from each other.

My question is following

1. Can camel provide abstraction so that i can write my service code without http, json and jms dependencies? I would like camel to handle http to java, json to java and jms to java conversion through some mediation and invocation of my service should be simply through a java method with accepts a java object as a request. Keep in mind that although http is synchronous model, jms would have to simulate request-response. If yes, can you please point me towards an example which demonstrates this setting.
2. Likewisely, i would like camel to convert the response from my service, which would be a java object, into json and return the response back to the client.
3. Lastly, how can i scale in this model. For JMS, it is easy to startup multiple instances and have them listen to a queue. How can i leverage same instances to loadbalance across http interfaces?  I would like services to have location transparency, hence, they should not have to care about invoking "jms" specific cluster vs "http" specific cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve all of this with Camel.

1. Marshalling between different object representations is handled through [data formats](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html). You can call [POJOs](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) from within Camel routes that can encapsulate your services.
2. See data formats.
3. Camel comes with [clustering](http://camel.apache.org/clustering-and-loadbalancing.html) and [load-balancing](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) support. But if you only have HTTP type endpoints to load balance, then my personal opinion is that you should use a more http-centric approach, like using httpd as a reverse proxy/load balancer.